# find the complexity of the counting sort algorithm line by line

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, counting-sort

How are you? Greetings to all of you.
I have a task and that is to find the complexity of the counting algorithm sort line by line to finally find the T(n). The truth is that it has been quite a complicated subject for me, but I have been working on this so I would like to know if someone with knowledge of this can tell me if it is right or wrong.
the pseudocode:

```
                                          cost            repetitions
  for i = 1 to k do                        2                 k+1
    c[i] = 0                               1                  k
  for j = 1 to n do                        2                 n+1
    c[A[j]] = c[A[j]] + 1                  2                  n
  for i = 2 to k do                        2                 k+2
    c[i] = c[i] + c[i-1]                   2                  k
  for j = n-1 downto 1 do                  2                 n+1
    B[ c[A[j]]] = A[j]                     1                  n
    c[A[j]] = c[A[j]] - 1                  2                  n
```

therefore t(n)= 2k+2+k+2n+2+2n+2k+4+2k+2n+2+n+n

T(n)=7k+8n+8

I'm not really sure about this analysis but it's the best I could do :v. thank you for any suggestion

Comment: So you have `Theta(k+n)` complexity (constant factors are ignored)

Comment: Thank you for answering. Yes, I do but I need to know if the line-by-line analysis is well done. That is to say if they are well analyzed, because then I have to find the witnesses c1 and c2 for ASYMPTOTIC ANALYSIS.

Comment: It is not simple question - answer depends on agreement: what operations should you take into account? You get number of +/- and assignments but ignore indirect addressing like `c[A[j]]` and `B[c[A[j]]]` (which might use addition at lower level). Should loop step involve two operations (increment and checking)?

Comment: what operations should you take into account?-I have researched says that you should always take the worst possible case is to say that algorithm has to sort all the numbers. hould loop step involve two operations (increment and checking)?I researched is that if it's an assignment the cost is 1 now if it's an assignment and sum is 2. knowing this would need to know if cost analysis and repetitions are okay